# How to start an Intent in an outsourced static function?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

I'm following this tutorial to get started with Bluetooth:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8R2C86BIUc

I want to outscource the bluetooth enable to an separated class and call it from the MainActivity.

I made the new Intent, but following the Video I'm not possible to start the Intent.

I tried importing:

```
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
```

But in both cases it didn't worked out.

Without any imports Android Studio is telling "Can't resolve method"

## MAIN

```
package com.example.lenkzeitapplikation_01;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startBT.switch_BT_ON();
    }

}
```

## STARTBT

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import com.fleetboard.sdk.lib.android.log.Log;


public class startBT {

    private static final String Tag ="StartBT";
    static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    public static void switch_BT_ON(){
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
            Log.d(Tag, "No BT adapter");
        }if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
           startActivity(enableBTIntent);

             //mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        }

    }

}
```

Using 
`import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat:`

> Error:
>   method startActivity in class ContextCompat cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: Context,Intent,Bundle
>   found: Intent
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: you need a Context instance to call `startActivity` on. Easy fix: call it like `startBT.switch_BT_ON();` and change the method signature to `switch_BT_ON(Context context)` and change the call to `context.startActivity(enableBTIntent)`

Comment: @Tim Castelijns can you Tell me what an Context instance is absolut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important**

Ok, first things first:
`Activity` is one of the different types of `Context`.
AND:
`startActivity` is a method that `Context` objects have.

**Explanation**

If you want to start an Activity, you must use a `Context` object. That's why it was working in the first place, in your `MainActivity`.

Now that you moved the code to another class, if you wan to use the method `startActivity`, you must have a reference to a `Context` object.

**But... How?**

```java
public class startBT {

    public static void switch_BT_ON(Context context){
        //... Your logic
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In your activity:

```java
startBT.switch_BT_ON(this);
```

The `this` parameter is the `MainActivity` itself, which is a `Context` by definition.

It means that:

`switch_BT_ON` requires a `Context`.

`MainActivity` is saying: "Here, use me".

**Recommendations**
This is classic, basic OOP thinking. Study about Object-Oriented Programming, classes and inheritance to learn why the `startActivity` method worked on the `Acivity` and not outside of it, passing objects around and handling different scopes.

Read the quick answer about [what is an Android `Context`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android). Or adventure yourself through [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context).